# Adding folder to Eclipse classpath

Tags: java, eclipse

While developing a Java project, I place all of my jar files in a folder, created within my project, called `libs.` Now, is there a way to add my `libs` folder to the Java class path so that I do not have to add each individual jar?

I was thinking something along the lines of a variable or creating a user library.

Comment: I have a similar question, because when run from the command line, you can say java -cp /my/libs/directory/*.jar name.of.Class.  This way, you could put this in a script or batch file, and maybe change out jar files without having to change the script (I'm sure there are reasons one would want to do this).  Surely there must be a simple way to just add an entry to the class path in Eclipse

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Based on what you've said, I would probably create a user library containing your library JARs.

You can create a User Library with Window => Preferences, drill down to Java => Build Path => User Libraries. => Then choose New, and give your library a name => Then add the JARs you want.

Then you can add all the JARs to the classpath of any project you have by right-clicking on the project => Add Libraries => User Libraries, and selecting your library.

---

Update; to have Eclipse dynamically add .jar files you drop into a folder to your project classpath, you need a plugin called [Library Folder ClasspathContainer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcontainer/). Follow [these instructions](http://libcontainer.sourceforge.net/) and you're in business.

Comment: I hear your idea/solution but its not what i am looking for. Basically for every new project i create i just want eclipse to pick up the libs folder in that project and automatically add the jars i place into it. Exactly like the WEB-INF/lib folder on a web project.

Comment: I see what you're looking for now. Looks like Eclipse can't do that out of the box, but there's a plugin here (http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcontainer/) that will automatically add .jars in a folder to your classpath. Hopefully that'll do the job. Trying it now...

Comment: Works a treat. Nice question - I'll use this myself!

Comment: I installed the mentioned plugin and it seems to work like a charm. Thanks a lot for this tip!