# How do I call selenium jar files from different directory to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium

Let's say, I have all required selenium jar files in c:\jarFiles, are there any other ways to call those jar files instead using java build path in eclipse?

Comment: You can add files from local folder to build path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I normally do that, but the only problem is that if  I want to change any jar file (let's say version of jar file changed), again we need to update the build path, I am looking for some kind of code or setting where I can only locate to the directory not to the jar files, hope my question is clear to you all...

Comment: You can use user library to achieve that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2458339/705773